# How can I automate creating IIS script mappings

Tags: iis, scripting, automation

I would like to automate the following task with a script
to create an IIS script mappings for my project:

- Go to Control Panel | Administrative Tools
- Open Internet Information Services
- Right-click the Default web site and select Properties.
- In the Properties dialog-box select the 'home Directory' tab.
- Click on the configuration button in the Application Configuration dialog.
- Click on the 'Add' button.

In the Add/Edit dialog-box, ensure the following settings are correct:

- for executable, put in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll
- for the extension, put in '*'
- for Verbs, select 'All verbs'
- select 'Script Engine' and leave 'Check that file exists' blank.

**Note:** The IIS v5.1 Manager console allows you to add '*' wild card extension names but IIS v6 manager does not. It is just a UI limitation. My box is WinXP.

Answer (score 0):

We have a script that does some updating to IIS, using javascript.

```
var iisPath = "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/" + siteID;
var site = GetObject(iisPath);
```

From here you should be able to do what you want.  You may need to look around the [object model.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525949.aspx)

You may also want to check out the article at : http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2005/07/13/HOWTO_Enumerate_IIS_Website_Configuration.aspx
and here is the specific info for the ScriptMaps property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526052.aspx